# Javascript helper for self resolving objects to use with promises like Angulars $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Angulars $resource has great feature to return objects that get their values injected and automagically update views. In the $resource service is a [Resource](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L655) object that gets the resolved result copied into itself with [shallowClearAndCopy()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L786) .

I would like to chain the promise returned from a $resource and get something like the Resource object that gets the deferred result injected.
(*Code example edited to return a object and require an argument.*)

```
var otherProperty = 'somethingChanging';
var lazyUser = $resource('/user/:userId').get({id:id});
var userDisplayNamePromise = lazyUser.$promise.then(transformResult);
function transformResult(user){
  return { displayName: user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname,
           other: user[otherProperty]
         };
}
```

currently I have to do something like

```
userDisplayNamePromise.then(updateDisplayUser);
function updateDisplayUser(displayName){$scope.user = displayName;}
```

and I would love to do something like

```
$scope.user = something(userDisplayNamePromise);
```

I couldn't find anything that would help me to use promises in such a easy way. Has anyone a good tip?

I have put a basic working example at [github.com/burka/resolvling](https://github.com/burka/resolvling/blob/master/resolvling.js). But I can't imagine that no one did that before?

Answer (score 1):

there are standard ways to transform response of an angular resource.

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roadprophet/prtAP/)

here is the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

*transformResponse – {function(data, headersGetter)|Array.} – transform function or an array of such functions. The transform function takes the http response body and headers and returns its transformed (typically deserialized) version. By default, transformResponse will contain one function that checks if the response looks like a JSON string and deserializes it using angular.fromJson. To prevent this behavior, set transformResponse to an empty array: transformResponse: []*

here is the sample code

```
angular.module('services', ['ngResource']).
factory("someService", function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        '/', {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function(data, headers){
                //MESS WITH THE DATA
                data = {};
                data.coolThing = 'BOOM-SHAKA-LAKA';
                return data;
            }
        }
    }

    );
});
```

Comment: I have some different transformations to do, dependent on data I would have to provide to the transforming function. For example I get a map of locale-translated mappings {list1:{a:1,b:2},list2:{d:"hello",f:"something"}}` that I get in one (cached) request but need the lists in different parts of the app. So I took the map access to a service and wanted to return a lazily initialized object instead of promise handling.

Comment: I changed the question accordingly by adding a argument that would have to be passed to the transforming function. Thanks for your help :-) Maybe I need to dig into the implementation... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unwrapping promises is a regular routine for asynchronous application and should be treated as inevitable.

The concept of self-filling object in `$resource` isn't conventional for asynchronous workflow, depending on its usage it may be considered an antipattern.

This is not possible, because `displayName` is expected to be a scalar value:

```
$scope.displayName = something(userDisplayNamePromise);
```

And this is something that `$q` promises aren't capable of without serious patchwork (as [the repo](https://github.com/burka/resolvling/blob/master/resolvling.js) demonstrates):

```
$scope.displayObj = something(userDisplayNamePromise);
```

While this may work for object bindings like `{{ displayObj.name }}`:

```
$scope.displayObj = userDisplayNamePromise.$$state.value;
```

But it should not be utilized in production - not only because internal `$$` properties aren't supposed to be used, but also because `$$state.value` may contain a value for rejected promise.

For ES6 environment or Babel-transpiled ES5, [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co) and generators [may be used to flatten promises](http://plnkr.co/edit/pEKt12tfer0lbLo6lLeS):

```
var wrap = (fn) => {
  return function(...args) {
    co(fn.bind(this, ...args));
  }
}

app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$q', wrap(function* ($scope, $q) {
  this.name = yield $q.resolve('World');
})]);
```

For ngRoute and UI Router, route resolvers may be used to inject resolved values to controllers and bind the values to scope, this is the most common way to get rid of unwrapping code.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't make a good job in providing the minimal viable example... I updated the question to reflect that I want to get a object as response and not a immutable object.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "The concept of self-filling object in $resource isn't conventional for asynchronous workflow, depending on its usage it may be considered an antipattern." ?
If it would be used without thought, I agree.. but I just need it for some self filling translated dropdown options, translations of labels and translation of some user settings. All just values displayed by angular and not further processed. Are there further reasons to avoid it?

Comment: Are the flashes of unprepared content wanted? Unlikely. Should half-baked view be shown to users if one of resources got spoilt? Doubtful. This is the perfect case for route/state resolver.

Comment: There's nothing really criminal in self-filling object, it just provides the magic that rarely benefits the design of the app in perspective. This is a matter of taste, but I consider [`js-data-angular`](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-angular)'s approach to model (`bindOne` and `bindAll`) more solid.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be a interesting project beeing able to do a lot more than what I want. I'll have a more throughout look at it later :-)